# The action cannot be completed because the file is open in httpd.exe

Tags: php, file, locked-files

I wrote JS to upload really large videos in chunks and PHP script to assemble the pieces on the server. The file process works except that I can't play the file unless I "Restart All Services" from the PHP taskbar.  After that the file plays fine.  If I try to rename the file in Windows Explorer I get the follow error:

> The action cannot be completed because the file is open in httpd.exe

I suspect it may have something to do with never calling `move_uploaded_File()`, but that calling that procedure won't work on the assembled file.

Comment: pls include the script in your question. or at least the piece of code responsible uploading videos.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself.  Nothing to do with move_uploaded_File not being called. There was a syntax error that stopped the script before the file was closed.  Since the server had been set to not display errors it wasn't apparent that an error occurred before the file was closed.

The temporary files are closed(explicitly) after being appended to large file being assembled.  It seems that this accomplishes part what move_uploaded_file does, that is, disposing of the temporary file after using it. The script ending probably does that too.